# How do i fix this code so it scrapes the info that i am looking for on the url provided?

Tags: python, web-scraping

here is the url that i am trying to scrape [Link](https://ebcbshp.healthsparq.com/healthsparq/public/#/one/city=&state=&postalCode=&country=&insurerCode=AGEBCBS_I&brandCode=AGEBCBS&alphaPrefix=&bcbsaProductId=/results/allRemote=false&alphaPrefix=&isPromotionSearch=false&key=Primary%2520Care%2520Provider&location=Manhattan%252C%2520NY%252010105&maxLatitude=&maxLongitude=&minLatitude=&minLongitude=&page=1&patientAge=&providerType=&query=Primary%2520Care%2520Provider&radius=25&searchType=PCP&searchCategory=SPECIALTY&sort=DEFAULT&waitForOop=false&doWebAlert=true&productCode=all&filter=LANGUAGE%253AHebrew&filter=LANGUAGE%253AYiddish)

This is the code that i have build so far:

```
import requests
import csv
import time

first_page = 1
last_page = 25
doctors = []

for current_page in range(first_page, last_page + 1):
    print('Scraping page {} of {}'.format(
        current_page,
        last_page
    ))
    r = requests.post(
        'https://ebcbshp.healthsparq.com/healthsparq/public/#/one/city=&state=&postalCode=&country=&insurerCode=AGEBCBS_I&brandCode=AGEBCBS&alphaPrefix=&bcbsaProductId=/results', 
        data='allRemote=false&alphaPrefix=&isPromotionSearch=false&key=Primary%2520Care%2520Provider&location=Manhattan%252C%2520NY%252010105&maxLatitude=&maxLongitude=&minLatitude=&minLongitude=&page=1&patientAge=&providerType=&query=Primary%2520Care%2520Provider&radius=25&searchType=PCP&searchCategory=SPECIALTY&sort=DEFAULT&waitForOop=false&doWebAlert=true&productCode=all&filter=LANGUAGE%253AHebrew&filter=LANGUAGE%253AYiddish'.format(current_page),
        headers={
            'authority': 'ebcbshp.healthsparq.com',
            'method': 'GET',
            'path': '/healthsparq/public/',
            'scheme': 'https',
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
            'cookie': 'visid_incap_2432633=6tvoniCNRNaDrmC2w1ybp0g052EAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAUgvSi4cElPTVbw241v3ND; tealiumid=017e6f24490a005224be2e32d68805072038e06a007e8; visit_num=1; _ga=GA1.2.1079271700.1642542159; _gid=GA1.2.52532984.1642542159; nlbi_2432633=mzNCX1Or22JwRAcxxFf2WwAAAADA6ddHInw8qDzSXKnrY/UE; trace-session-id=509cb8be-7d5d-4e56-9903-355b3a980564; visid_incap_2432632=fizlJV9TTAyB5wCLP8vH4noy6GEAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABbQWBR2zaXAJvBu3jg9UMy; nlbi_2432632=f1I6cvVGxBeP6GJfBAiJ0QAAAAA9TxT0sRpwNRActkvEcgIo; incap_ses_1459_2432633=CxdiUuNEXVcm36kM6Gg/FO7K6GEAAAAAMnD35+7EhHsj79Mtum5rJA==; SESSION=ODBhMWNjYTgtMWFlNS00ODY0LTliZDgtM2U5NzhiMjEzM2Vk; incap_ses_1459_2432632=7imDKmcXbXgzXbQM6Gg/FCDg6GEAAAAAWZsfV28AYp98pSpiOaPd3g==; nlbi_2432633_2147483646=hfh2OdUFM25+NsVPxFf2WwAAAAAxDvOyZiQjCJ46b0eeOdEW; reese84=3:tnNErCRUjYxtjtZGakx3mA==:mehYTYdRnFlRPkyeM6+vkbiz5wsHlG85px+G6BEu7mBSkK23evQM0WWQMWsxitFULdc8wFsxwcACPDMdhLDyjKXQ3tKKCxAPk9aFoI1r9Q9VsXCElHERnLE/QuZe4KDvGlTehhaGiTl0eABxFR1sIpXTPUUYmnsbpuOF5y61EcznXCL0PPKJyVENIcducyhycoc0JOswOXXVIvFHIjbeiyVC3x2ISAk0v4AaVuxnpfod4KFDyFyq7qyf47EPtSHS/QI7fsjTfRLkWuJyU8XeDp/WPdrC41bGX1LSfJETrOeFZg5cNxqdsAdrXOVma/3wevK+bEXbbHSllfvvGIX/Tf3CwUE76WvFcUfw4Kgibard45rAfC6hSYG5/nqCWRdkV/naKZbBNXS6zbmOHm9L4PJNaleGGq643YKOf8IU0LrXx6Ak6A7JTTgNspRa6e4H:qRM1rYjjlvVfvLF/fGH5MTkO4xIAvwnjxSqf5Gis7RM=; prev_page_ppv=25; utag_main=v_id:017e6f24490a005224be2e32d68805072038e06a007e8$_sn:7$_se:316$_ss:0$_st:1642656317806$_ga:017e6f24490a005224be2e32d68805072038e06a007e8$ses_id:1642646948305%3Bexp-session$_pn:5%3Bexp-session',
            'if-modified-since': 'Mon, 10 Jan 2022 19:15:38 GMT',
            'sec-ch-ua' : 'Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'Windows',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36'
        }
    )
    response = r.json()
    if len(response['results']):
        for provider in response['results'][0]['providers']:
            doctors.append({
                'first_name': provider['firstName'],
                'last_name': provider['lastName'],
                'address': provider['bestLocation']['addressLine1'],
                'city': provider['bestLocation']['city'],
                'state': provider['bestLocation']['state'],
                'zip': provider['bestLocation']['zip'],
                'country': provider['bestLocation']['country'],
                'specialties': ','.join([x['specialtyName'] for x in provider['providerSpecialties']]),
                'office_phone_number': provider['bestLocation']['officePhoneNumber'],
                'fax_number': provider['bestLocation']['faxNumber']
            })
    else:
        print('Out of index')

csv_filename = 'listofproviders_1_{}.csv'.format(time.time())
with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, doctors[0].keys())
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(doctors)
```

These are the errors that i am getting. Tried a few things, not sure how to fix it. Please some help would be appreciated:

Scraping page 1 of 25
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Somebody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Somebody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\Somebody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\Somebody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Somebody\OneDrive - One\Somebody - Projects\Project A\PrimaryCareProvider.py", line 39, in 
response = r.json()
File "C:\Users\Somebody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 917, in json
raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 1459000150145490726-88597805248218054: 0
PS C:\Users\Somebody\OneDrive - One\Somebody - Projects\Project A>

Comment: First, that url doesnot return a json structure. Secondly, the url you want to post to is `https://ebcbshp.healthsparq.com/healthsparq/public/service/v2/search/point`. Third, they block automated requests as when you do try it you will get `Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident`

Comment: @chitown88 so what suggestions do you have to fix this? Anything?

Comment: you might need to go the route of using something like Selenium. This will let the page render, then you can pull the html, parse it, then go to the next page.

Comment: Even then, it may not work as the server might be detecting a bot.